# Android studio custom button style padding issues

Tags: android, android-button, android-theme, material-components-android

After 4 months of being inactive i realized that there are some changes.

Now when you make a new button it is purple and has some padding defined. Managed to kill the purple color by editing the theme, but i still have issues with padding. When i make a new button, by default it has left and right padding 16dp, and top and bottom 4. I would not like to be forced to change every single new button to 0 padding..

i have 2 options in mind. To set padding in custom button xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    
    <corners android:radius="12dp" />
    <solid android:color="#000000" />
    
    <padding
    
    android:left="0dp"
    
    android:top="0dp"
    
    android:right="0dp"
    
    android:bottom="0dp" />
    
    </shape>
```

...but for some reason this doesnt work.

Can someone figure out what can be the issue?

Or to tell me how can i change default padding values for new buttons?

Also values for some insetBotton and insetTop to be set to 0 by default and not 6

Comment: Are you using a Material Component theme?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a Material Components theme the `Button` is replaced at runtime by a `MaterialButton`.

The `MaterialButton` has a default style with `insetBottom` and `insetTop` with a value of `6dp`.

If you want to **change globally** the button style in your app you can also add the `materialButtonStyle` attribute in your app theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.*">
   <item name="materialButtonStyle">@style/Widget.App.Button</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.App.Button" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">....</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">...</item>
    <item name="android:insetTop">...</item>
    <item name="android:insetBottom">....</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Bravo!!! Thats was it! Thank you sooooo much!!! :)))

Answer (score 1):

Go to your `res` folder -> `values` -> `styles`
Insert the following lines below to edit the **standard** `button` et voilà:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="android:minWidth">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">0dp</item>
</style>
```

That should work, give it a shot buddy.

Comment: do you mean like this? <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners android:radius="12dp" />
    <solid android:color="#000000" />


    <item name="android:minHeight">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:minWidth">0dp</item>

    <padding android:left="0dp"
        android:top="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:bottom="0dp" />

</shape> because this gives error

Comment: and about this to add  definitions to the button itself. i would like to avoid adding padding and inset definitions to every single button. i think that it will make code much larger unnecessary. i am trying to find the way to change this globally, without editing every single button. Plus, i have bigger issues with padding left and right

Comment: Thank you this answer worked perfectly for me. This should be ticked as the right one.

Comment: In this way you are just defining a **style** to apply to each `Button` in the xml layout. Also you are using a `AppCompat` style in a Material Components Theme, **losing** some of the Material Components features.

Comment: I get what you mean. But I think both will work for the needs of a specific project. Thanks for making some thoughts! I guess we are both on the right way. Strong present from your site. Keep going buddy! :)